# Better to use zero-date '0000-00-00 00:00:00' or NULL in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Is it a better practice to use default date '0000-00-00 00:00:00' or `NULL` on a MySQL database?

I have read best to use default date '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for the reason of calculations

*i.e.* `>`than a date less than a date.

Also on time best to store `00:00` or `NULL` if time is not known.

Comment: Use `NULL`. `0000-00-00 00:00:00` is not a valid Date (and MySQL's JDBC driver will refuse to load that btw). For the time you **have** to use `NULL` because 00:00 is a real time (midnight). So you couldn't distinguish between midnight and "no time".

Comment: I typically use null to mean "unknown". As long as you know what value you assign, you can use that if your app handles it correctly

Comment: You really need to be checking for error states anyway (i.e. NULL dates where a valid date is expected).

Comment: IF you are expecting a value, your default should not be `NULL`.

Comment: If you might not have a value, you shouldn't be expecting one.

Comment: I've seen `0000-00-00 00:00:00` only by some developers, who always want to substring `date.toString()`. Why? I don't know...

Comment: say for example i want to order things by date and the field is not required in the table how would mysql handle the ordering of null values

Comment: if it was default date '0000-00-00 00:00:00' and i ordered by datetime the item would order with the latestes entry first

Comment: @MatthewChambers That's a *different* problem with different solutions (which do exist, search for *that issue*).

Comment: pst am i best using null still in this instance

Comment: @MatthewChambers Make the data represent what it should. NULL is "none" or "missing" or "unknown", depending on the semantic context it is in. There *may* be a need to separate between the three, in which case a [valid] sentinel value might be used (although I would argue for a schema normalization/update to capture this information). How NULL compares with other values is not relevant at this point.

Comment: MySQL permits you to store a “zero” value of '0000-00-00' as a “dummy date.” This is in some cases more convenient than using NULL values, and uses less data and index space. To disallow '0000-00-00', enable the NO_ZERO_DATE SQL mode.

Comment: read here - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-types.html

Answer (score -4, accepted):

a default value should be NOT NULL inorder to support all date time operations.
i also uses "0000-00-00 00:00:00" as default value.

Comment: @MatthewChambers http://www.fromdual.com/using-null-as-default-values discusses the opposite to be the right answer, although personally I think that using the default 0000-00-00 is better. There is one operation that is mentioned it it's comments which does not work if the field can be null `SELECT * FROM t WHERE city=city`

Comment: I agree with @MatthewChambers that 0000-00-00 is the best answer.

Comment: NULL means the lack of a value/"unknown": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL). Handling nulls means you code in a way that is less idiosyncratic to MySQL. I also believe it can introduce comprehensibility issues e.g. if you query for date column < some concrete date, then 0000-00-00's will also be returned. If 0000-00-00 means 'unknown' then these results are incorrect because how can you be sure 'unknown' is really less than (or > or =) a concrete date? Alternatively, if 0000-00-00 does *not* mean 'unknown' (i.e. 0000-00-00 < 2015-01-01 is valid), then all developers must agree/learn why

Comment: it's a very bad practice to use bogus values to represent `unknown`, you're likely to end up in situations where `00:00:00`, `2031-01-01 00:00:00`, `1970-01-01` etc. are used as `unkowns` and it's not clear which values are used as unkowns and which aren't. In SQL there is already an explicit value for this, `NULL`, use that

Answer (score 6):

You should use `NULL` because `0000-00-00 00:00:00` is not a valid date. If you use libraries such as [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) or [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) to manage date, they both know how to deal with  `NULL` dates.

The MySQL configuration should always be set to:

```
SET sql_mode = 'NO_ZERO_DATE';
```

unless you have to deal with an old database.

That said, according to [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-types.html):

> MySQL permits you to store a “zero” value of '0000-00-00' as a “dummy date.” This is in some cases more convenient than using NULL values, and uses less data and index space. To disallow '0000-00-00', enable the NO_ZERO_DATE mode.

If you are on Windows:

> “Zero” date or time values used through Connector/ODBC are converted automatically to NULL because ODBC cannot handle such values.

An additional point to consider is: what is the true meaning of a zero date?

- Does '0000-00-00' < '2018-12-12'?
- Does '0000-00-00' means 'unknown'?
- Does '0000-00-00' means 'null'?

Unless your answer is the first one and you need to do comparisons with null dates, using a `NULL` value is always less confusing.

Comment: +1. I just got done tracking down a production bug where a few values of '0000-00-00 00:00' were present in an (ostensibly) non-null MySQL DATETIME column -- and ActiveRecord / Rails cheerfully read in those values as `nil`, triggering a `NoMethodError: undefined method '>' for nil:NilClass` when trying to do a date comparison on them.

Answer (score 5):

MySQL 5.7 defaults to disallowing `0000-00-00 00:00:00` as default value, unless you set `sql_mode = ''`. It seems MySQL wants you to use `NULL` as default value.