# Date getting stored as 0000-00-00 in mysql database?

Tags: php, android, mysql, date

I have a android app that sends data to mysql database using google's volley library.When the data gets saved into the database it's in this format 0000-00-00.
This is the php code I am trying to implement.

```
<?php

        include "config.php";
        $dbname =$_POST["dbname"];
        $con = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$dbname);
         if(!$con)
         {
                         echo "Connection Error".mysqli_connect_error();
         }
         else{
        //echo "";
         }

        $arrAssoc = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['jsonarray']), true);
        $values="";
        foreach($arrAssoc as $aa){
                //echo "<pre>";print_r($aa);exit;
                $values.="(";
                $values.=" '".$aa['doc_no']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['date']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['cust_name']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['cust_number']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['item_count']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['total_wt']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['sub_total']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['discount']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['vat']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['paid']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['urd_less']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['total']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['balance']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['bill_type']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['status']."'";
                $values.="),";
        }
        $values=rtrim($values,',');

        $query="INSERT INTO billing_all(doc_no, date,cust_name, cust_number, item_count,total_wt,sub_total,discount,vat,paid,urd_less,total,balance,bill_type,status)VALUES".$values;

        if(mysqli_query($con,$query))
        {
        echo "Data inserted";
        }else
        {
       echo "Data insertion error".mysqli_error($con);
        }


?>
```

This is the java code for date.

```
//code for date
        java.util.Date dt = new java.util.Date();
        java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        final String date = sdf.format(dt);
```

And this is my database structure :-
[image]

Is there a way I can solve this problem without disturbing my existing structure.I am new to programming so any help or suggestion is appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: can provide here the date which are posted in php?

Comment: Can you stop using `VALUES".$values`, this is [dangerous](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: you're still not providing the date. Which format are you inserting it in?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215331/php-mysql-date-saved-as-0000-00-00?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DateFormat in java is wrong, it should be:

```
java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: This actually solves the problem but can't we save it as 07-JUN-2016 instead?

Comment: @AndroidNewBee no you can't, SQL date format is yyyy-MM-dd.

Answer (score 0):

USE `DATE_FORMAT` and `STR_TO_DATE`

```
date_format(str_to_date(date_column,'dd-MMMM-yyyy'),'%Y-%m-%d')
```