# Why Different Results Using Mysql Queries

Tags: mysql

I have two queries. No error in these queries just results are different.

**Query 1**

```
SELECT * FROM notices
WHERE CURDATE( ) < end_date
OR end_date = NULL
ORDER BY id
```

**Result of Query One:**

[image]

**Query 2**

```
select * from notices
where CURDATE() < end_date or end_date='0000-00-00' 
order by id
```

**Result of Query Two:**

[image]

**Table Structure**

[image]

**Question**

**My Question is that why query 1 not showing the same results as query 2 showing?**

Comment: Essentially, you're asking why two different queries produce different results :) In the first query, you're checking if end_date is NULL specifically, while the second one checks if the end_date is also equal to '0000-00-00'.

Comment: But when i insert i use `NULL` for end date then it save `0000-00-00`. So according to this i am saying that during selection why it is not working with `NULL`

Comment: It's now sounding like the end_date column includes `NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00'` in its definition. That would mean that, when a row gets inserted into the database, if `end_date` is missing, '0000-00-00' will be used in its place. Please update your question with your table schema

Comment: why Negative mark to question?

Answer (score 1):

Because NULL is not the same as "0000-00-00"

PD: If you want to set a where clause and select where field is null you should use "WHERE end_date IS NULL", not "WHERE end_date = NULL"

Comment: if it is not same then why it save NULL as `0000-00-00` ?

Comment: @HamzaZafeer then you are probably saving NULL wrong, show us that code. Or check this example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4bf612/1

Comment: Your end_date column is not nullable. Your ORM or whatever must be saving a default value instead of NULL

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding NULL is different from 0000-00-00 for Date type.Some developer use 0000-00-00 as a default value. Since both NULL and 0000-00-00 are different, you are seeing two different resultsets.

Check this [default date '0000-00-00 00:00:00' or null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482560/default-date-0000-00-00-000000-or-null)